# Find all lines that are printing to stdout in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Google is not helping me out. I have a large Rails project that is riddled with print statements or something of that sort. Something is printing and I can't find out what. I have looked at the specs and I can't find anything that should be printing output.

Is there a flag I can pass to rspec or ruby that will show what line number printed to console?

Or perhaps a grep command EG `grep -Rl 'p "'` to try and hunt down all these print statements?

My rspec output looks like this:

```
""
..*.****.......*****.........**.""
...""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
.""
...**.......""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$stdout` and `$stderr` are variables!  Somewhere early in your test config (spec_helper, probably)

```
class MyIO < IO
  def puts(*)
    debugger
    super
  end
end

$stdout = $stderr = MyIO.new
```

MyIO may need to have a more concrete superclass - like StringIO or File.

You'll probably just need to run that once to find the culprit.  If you find it's getting called too often with stuff you are OK seeing, maybe tweak the debugger line to be something complicated `debugger unless caller_is_whitelisted`

```
def caller_is_whitelisted
  return true if caller[2 (give or take)].matches(/some_file_that_may_print/)
  ...
  false
end
```

This is all really rough code and super gross - but you have a gross problem and it's temporary.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and solves what I need. I really just needed to locate these lines as they were called so I could find them. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(aimed to be a comment)

It looks like some kind of progress bar, is there any download, or loading in your script? may be in required dependencies.

You may try to redirect stderr on the command line (2>NUL on windows 2>/dev/null on linux) to see if these lines disappears.

There might also be some option keep those lines quiet (like --quiete --silent or anything similar)